# An isomorphism of the fibers in abelian varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I read a PDF ["Projectivity of Abelian varieties"](http://www2.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/%7Ebakkerbe/Abelian7.pdf) for learning the theory of abelian variety.However I am a beginner, so there is some part that I don't understand. About the first statement of proof of Proposition 6, why do we obtain an isomorphism of the fibers $t_x∣_{α^{−1}(0)} : α^{-1}(0) \rightarrow α^{-1}(y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially just the fact, that you surely know, that if $f:G\to H$ is a homomorphism of groups then for every $g\in G$ one has that

$$f^{-1}(f(g))=g\ker(f)$$

Indeed, if $g'\in f^{-1}(f(g))$ then $f(g)=f(g')$ so that $f(g^{-1}g')=e$ so $g'g^{-1}\in \ker (f)$. So then, $g'=g(g^{-1}g')\in g\ker(f)$. Conversely, if $g'\in g\ker(f)$ then $g'=gk$ with $k\in\ker(f)$ so then $f(g')=f(gk)=f(g)f(k)=f(g)e=f(g)$. So, $g'\in f^{-1}(f(g))$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I apologize for my lack of ability, but I still don't get the first statement of proof of Proposition 6. I understand $f^{-1}(f(g))=g\ker(f)$. However, why is this statement useful in this case? $X$ and $Y$ are abelian varieties. In particular they are group objects in the category of schemes, so for all scheme $S$ $X(S)$ and $Y(S)$ are groups. But to use the theorem which should we take a scheme?

Comment: @user816697 I think this person is being somewhat imprecise. Namely, by upper semicontinuity of fiber dimension it suffices to work with $y$ which is an $\overline{k}$-point (if $k$ is the field we're working over) and, in particular, since dimension is insensitive to base change it suffices to assume that $k=\overline{k}$. Then, the point is that the equality $f^{-1}(f(g))=g\ker(f)$ holds for every $k$-algeba $R$ functorially. And, so one has an actual equality of schemes.

Comment: I see. In particularly this case, for $α:X \to Y$ and all $g \in X$ $α^{-1}(α(g))=g\ker(α)=gα^{-1}(0)$ and so in particular taking $x \in α^{-1}(y)$ as $g$ $α^{-1}(α(x))=xα^{-1}(0)$. Since $α^{-1}(α(x))=xα^{-1}(0)$ $α^{-1}(0)$ and $α^{-1}(y)$ are isomorphic, aren't they? I don’t have confidence in myself.

Comment: Yes, that seems correct!

Comment: I understand! Thank you for everything!